# convert javascript function to php function hindi fonts to unicode converter

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to convert the source code of javascript to php source code similar logic. So that the functionlity of function remains same but php code can directly used in php without using any overhead code.

```
function convert_to_unicode(text) {
const array_one = new Array(
    // "(",")", 
    "ñ", "Q+Z", "sas", "aa", ")Z", "ZZ", "‘", "’", "“", "”",
    "å", "ƒ", "„", "…", "†", "‡", "ˆ", "‰", "Š", "‹",
    "¶+", "d+", "[+k", "[+", "x+", "T+", "t+", "M+", "<+", "Q+", ";+", "j+", "u+",
    "Ùk", "Ù", "ä", "–", "—", "é", "™", "=kk", "f=k",
    "à", "á", "â", "ã", "ºz", "º", "í", "{k", "{", "=", "«",
    "Nî", "Vî", "Bî", "Mî", "<î", "|", "K", "}",
    "J", "Vª", "Mª", "<ªª", "Nª", "Ø", "Ý", "nzZ", "æ", "ç", "Á", "xz", "#", ":",
    "v‚", "vks", "vkS", "vk", "v", "b±", "Ã", "bZ", "b", "m", "Å", ",s", ",", "_",
    "ô", "d", "Dk", "D", "[k", "[", "x", "Xk", "X", "Ä", "?k", "?", "³",
    "pkS", "p", "Pk", "P", "N", "t", "Tk", "T", ">", "÷", "¥",
    "ê", "ë", "V", "B", "ì", "ï", "M+", "<+", "M", "<", ".k", ".",
    "r", "Rk", "R", "Fk", "F", ")", "n", "/k", "èk", "/", "Ë", "è", "u", "Uk", "U",
    "i", "Ik", "I", "Q", "¶", "c", "Ck", "C", "Hk", "H", "e", "Ek", "E",
    ";", "¸", "j", "y", "Yk", "Y", "G", "o", "Ok", "O",
    "'k", "'", "\"k", "\"", "l", "Lk", "L", "g",
    "È", "z",
    "Ì", "Í", "Î", "Ï", "Ñ", "Ò", "Ó", "Ô", "Ö", "Ø", "Ù", "Ük", "Ü",
    "‚", "ks", "kS", "k", "h", "q", "w", "`", "s", "S",
    "a", "¡", "%", "W", "•", "·", "∙", "·", "~j", "~", "\\", "+", " ः",
    "^", "*", "Þ", "ß", "(", "¼", "½", "¿", "À", "¾", "A", "-", "&", "&", "Œ", "]", "~ ", "@");
const array_two = new Array(
    //"¼","½", 
    "॰", "QZ+", "sa", "a", "र्द्ध", "Z", "\"", "\"", "'", "'",
    "०", "१", "२", "३", "४", "५", "६", "७", "८", "९",
    "फ़्", "क़", "ख़", "ख़्", "ग़", "ज़्", "ज़", "ड़", "ढ़", "फ़", "य़", "ऱ", "ऩ",    // one-byte nukta varNas
    "त्त", "त्त्", "क्त", "दृ", "कृ", "न्न", "न्न्", "=k", "f=",
    "ह्न", "ह्य", "हृ", "ह्म", "ह्र", "ह्", "द्द", "क्ष", "क्ष्", "त्र", "त्र्",
    "छ्य", "ट्य", "ठ्य", "ड्य", "ढ्य", "द्य", "ज्ञ", "द्व",
    "श्र", "ट्र", "ड्र", "ढ्र", "छ्र", "क्र", "फ्र", "र्द्र", "द्र", "प्र", "प्र", "ग्र", "रु", "रू",
    "ऑ", "ओ", "औ", "आ", "अ", "ईं", "ई", "ई", "इ", "उ", "ऊ", "ऐ", "ए", "ऋ",
    "क्क", "क", "क", "क्", "ख", "ख्", "ग", "ग", "ग्", "घ", "घ", "घ्", "ङ",
    "चै", "च", "च", "च्", "छ", "ज", "ज", "ज्", "झ", "झ्", "ञ",
    "ट्ट", "ट्ठ", "ट", "ठ", "ड्ड", "ड्ढ", "ड़", "ढ़", "ड", "ढ", "ण", "ण्",
    "त", "त", "त्", "थ", "थ्", "द्ध", "द", "ध", "ध", "ध्", "ध्", "ध्", "न", "न", "न्",
    "प", "प", "प्", "फ", "फ्", "ब", "ब", "ब्", "भ", "भ्", "म", "म", "म्",
    "य", "य्", "र", "ल", "ल", "ल्", "ळ", "व", "व", "व्",
    "श", "श्", "ष", "ष्", "स", "स", "स्", "ह",
    "ीं", "्र",
    "द्द", "ट्ट", "ट्ठ", "ड्ड", "कृ", "भ", "्य", "ड्ढ", "झ्", "क्र", "त्त्", "श", "श्",
    "ॉ", "ो", "ौ", "ा", "ी", "ु", "ू", "ृ", "े", "ै",
    "ं", "ँ", "ः", "ॅ", "ऽ", "ऽ", "ऽ", "ऽ", "्र", "्", "?", "़", ":",
    "‘", "’", "“", "”", ";", "(", ")", "{", "}", "=", "।", ".", "-", "µ", "॰", ",", "् ", "/");

var array_one_length = array_one.length;
var modified_substring = text;
//****************************************************************************************
//  Break the long text into small bunches of max. max_text_size  characters each.
//****************************************************************************************
var text_size = modified_substring.length;

var processed_text = '';  //blank

var sthiti1 = 0; var sthiti2 = 0; var chale_chalo = 1;

var max_text_size = 6000;

while (chale_chalo == 1) {
    sthiti1 = sthiti2;

    if (sthiti2 < (text_size - max_text_size)) {
        sthiti2 += max_text_size;
        while (modified_substring.charAt(sthiti2) != ' ') { sthiti2--; }
    }
    else { sthiti2 = text_size; chale_chalo = 0 }
    var modified_substring = modified_substring.substring(sthiti1, sthiti2);
    Replace_Symbols();
    processed_text += modified_substring;
}

function Replace_Symbols() {
    if (modified_substring != "")
    {
        for (input_symbol_idx = 0; input_symbol_idx < array_one_length; input_symbol_idx++) 
        {
            idx = 0;
            while (idx != -1)
            {
               modified_substring = modified_substring.replace(array_one[input_symbol_idx], array_two[input_symbol_idx])
               idx = modified_substring.indexOf(array_one[input_symbol_idx])
            }
        }
        modified_substring = modified_substring.replace(/±/g, "Zं"); // at some places  ì  is  used eg  in "कर्कंधु,पूर्णांक".
        modified_substring = modified_substring.replace(/Æ/g, "र्f");  // at some places  Æ  is  used eg  in "धार्मिक".
        var position_of_i = modified_substring.indexOf("f")
        while (position_of_i != -1)  //while-02
        {
            var charecter_next_to_i = modified_substring.charAt(position_of_i + 1)
            var charecter_to_be_replaced = "f" + charecter_next_to_i
            modified_substring = modified_substring.replace(charecter_to_be_replaced, charecter_next_to_i + "ि")
            position_of_i = modified_substring.search(/f/, position_of_i + 1) // search for i ahead of the current position.

        } 
        modified_substring = modified_substring.replace(/Ç/g, "fa"); // at some places  Ç  is  used eg  in "किंकर".
        modified_substring = modified_substring.replace(/É/g, "र्fa"); // at some places  É  is  used eg  in "शर्मिंदा"
        var position_of_i = modified_substring.indexOf("fa")
        while (position_of_i != -1)  //while-02
        {
            var charecter_next_to_ip2 = modified_substring.charAt(position_of_i + 2)
            var charecter_to_be_replaced = "fa" + charecter_next_to_ip2
            modified_substring = modified_substring.replace(charecter_to_be_replaced, charecter_next_to_ip2 + "िं")
            position_of_i = modified_substring.search(/fa/, position_of_i + 2) // search for i ahead of the current position.

        }
        ;
        modified_substring = modified_substring.replace(/Ê/g, "ीZ"); // at some places  Ê  is  used eg  in "किंकर".
        var position_of_wrong_ee = modified_substring.indexOf("ि्")
        while (position_of_wrong_ee != -1)  //while-03
        {
            var consonent_next_to_wrong_ee = modified_substring.charAt(position_of_wrong_ee + 2)
            var charecter_to_be_replaced = "ि्" + consonent_next_to_wrong_ee
            modified_substring = modified_substring.replace(charecter_to_be_replaced, "्" + consonent_next_to_wrong_ee + "ि")
            position_of_wrong_ee = modified_substring.search(/ि्/, position_of_wrong_ee + 2) // search for 'wrong ee' ahead of the current position. 

        }
        set_of_matras = "अ आ इ ई उ ऊ ए ऐ ओ औ ा ि ी ु ू ृ े ै ो ौ ं : ँ ॅ"
        var position_of_R = modified_substring.indexOf("Z")
        while (position_of_R > 0)  // while-04
        {
            probable_position_of_half_r = position_of_R - 1;
            var charecter_at_probable_position_of_half_r = modified_substring.charAt(probable_position_of_half_r)
            while (set_of_matras.match(charecter_at_probable_position_of_half_r) != null)  // while-05
            {
                probable_position_of_half_r = probable_position_of_half_r - 1;
                charecter_at_probable_position_of_half_r = modified_substring.charAt(probable_position_of_half_r);
            } 
            charecter_to_be_replaced = modified_substring.substr(probable_position_of_half_r, (position_of_R - probable_position_of_half_r));
            new_replacement_string = "र्" + charecter_to_be_replaced;
            charecter_to_be_replaced = charecter_to_be_replaced + "Z";
            modified_substring = modified_substring.replace(charecter_to_be_replaced, new_replacement_string);
            position_of_R = modified_substring.indexOf("Z");
        }
    }
}
return processed_text;
}
```

I have converted part of the code but it's working similar to javascript

```html
<?php
function charAt($str,$pos) {
    return (substr($str,$pos,1) !== false) ? substr($str,$pos,1) : -1;
}
function convert_to_unicode($text)
{
 $array_one = array( 
  // "(",")", 
  "ñ","Q+Z","sas","aa",")Z","ZZ","‘","’","“","”",
  "å",  "ƒ",  "„",   "…",   "†",   "‡",   "ˆ",   "‰",   "Š",   "‹", 
  "¶+",   "d+", "[+k","[+", "x+",  "T+",  "t+", "M+", "<+", "Q+", ";+", "j+", "u+",
  "Ùk", "Ù", "ä", "–", "—","é","™","=kk","f=k",  
  "à",   "á",    "â",   "ã",   "ºz",  "º",   "í", "{k", "{", "=",  "«",   
  "Nî",   "Vî",    "Bî",   "Mî",   "<î", "|", "K", "}",
  "J",   "Vª",   "Mª",  "<ªª",  "Nª",   "Ø",  "Ý", "nzZ",  "æ", "ç", "Á", "xz", "#", ":",
  "v‚","vks",  "vkS",  "vk",    "v",  "b±", "Ã",  "bZ",  "b",  "m",  "Å",  ",s",  ",",   "_",
  "ô",  "d", "Dk", "D", "[k", "[", "x","Xk", "X", "Ä", "?k", "?",   "³", 
  "pkS",  "p", "Pk", "P",  "N",  "t", "Tk", "T",  ">", "÷", "¥",
  "ê",  "ë",   "V",  "B",   "ì",   "ï", "M+", "<+", "M",  "<", ".k", ".",    
  "r",  "Rk", "R",   "Fk", "F",  ")", "n", "/k", "èk",  "/", "Ë", "è", "u", "Uk", "U",   
  "i",  "Ik", "I",   "Q",    "¶",  "c", "Ck",  "C",  "Hk",  "H", "e", "Ek",  "E",
  ";",  "¸",   "j",    "y", "Yk",  "Y",  "G",  "o", "Ok", "O",
  "'k", "'",   "\"k",  "\"",  "l", "Lk",  "L",   "g", 
  "È", "z", 
  "Ì", "Í", "Î",  "Ï",  "Ñ",  "Ò",  "Ó",  "Ô",   "Ö",  "Ø",  "Ù","Ük", "Ü",
  "‚",    "ks",   "kS",   "k",  "h",    "q",   "w",   "`",    "s",    "S",
  "a",    "¡",    "%",     "W",  "•", "·", "∙", "·", "~j",  "~", "\\","+"," ः",
  "^", "*",  "Þ", "ß", "(", "¼", "½", "¿", "À", "¾", "A", "-", "&", "&", "Œ", "]","~ ","@");
 $array_two = array(
  //"¼","½", 
  "॰","QZ+","sa","a","र्द्ध","Z","\"","\"","'","'",
  "०",  "१",  "२",  "३",     "४",   "५",  "६",   "७",   "८",   "९",   
  "फ़्",  "क़",  "ख़", "ख़्",  "ग़", "ज़्", "ज़",  "ड़",  "ढ़",   "फ़",  "य़",  "ऱ",  "ऩ",    // one-byte nukta varNas
  "त्त", "त्त्", "क्त",  "दृ",  "कृ","न्न","न्न्","=k","f=",
  "ह्न",  "ह्य",  "हृ",  "ह्म",  "ह्र",  "ह्",   "द्द",  "क्ष", "क्ष्", "त्र", "त्र्", 
  "छ्य",  "ट्य",  "ठ्य",  "ड्य",  "ढ्य", "द्य", "ज्ञ", "द्व",
  "श्र",  "ट्र",    "ड्र",    "ढ्र",    "छ्र",   "क्र",  "फ्र", "र्द्र",  "द्र",   "प्र", "प्र",  "ग्र", "रु",  "रू",
  "ऑ",   "ओ",  "औ",  "आ",   "अ", "ईं", "ई",  "ई",   "इ",  "उ",   "ऊ",  "ऐ",  "ए", "ऋ",
  "क्क", "क", "क", "क्", "ख", "ख्", "ग", "ग", "ग्", "घ", "घ", "घ्", "ङ",
  "चै",  "च", "च", "च्", "छ", "ज", "ज", "ज्",  "झ",  "झ्", "ञ",
  "ट्ट",   "ट्ठ",   "ट",   "ठ",   "ड्ड",   "ड्ढ",  "ड़", "ढ़", "ड",   "ढ", "ण", "ण्",   
  "त", "त", "त्", "थ", "थ्",  "द्ध",  "द", "ध", "ध", "ध्", "ध्", "ध्", "न", "न", "न्",    
  "प", "प", "प्",  "फ", "फ्",  "ब", "ब", "ब्",  "भ", "भ्",  "म",  "म", "म्",  
  "य", "य्",  "र", "ल", "ल", "ल्",  "ळ",  "व", "व", "व्",   
  "श", "श्",  "ष", "ष्", "स", "स", "स्", "ह", 
  "ीं", "्र",    
  "द्द", "ट्ट","ट्ठ","ड्ड","कृ","भ","्य","ड्ढ","झ्","क्र","त्त्","श","श्",
  "ॉ",  "ो",   "ौ",   "ा",   "ी",   "ु",   "ू",   "ृ",   "े",   "ै",
  "ं",   "ँ",   "ः",   "ॅ",  "ऽ", "ऽ", "ऽ", "ऽ", "्र",  "्", "?", "़",":",
  "‘",   "’",   "“",   "”",  ";",  "(",    ")",   "{",    "}",   "=", "।", ".", "-",  "µ", "॰", ",","् ","/");
 $array_one_length = sizeof($array_one);
 $modified_substring = $text;
 $text_size = strlen($modified_substring);
 $processed_text = '' ;  //blank
 $sthiti1 = 0 ;  
 $sthiti2 = 0 ;  
 $chale_chalo = 1 ;
 $max_text_size = 6000;
 while ( $chale_chalo == 1 ) 
 {
  $sthiti1 = $sthiti2 ;
  if ( $sthiti2 < ( $text_size - $max_text_size ) )  
  { 
   $sthiti2 +=  $max_text_size ;
   while (charAt($modified_substring,$sthiti2) != ' ') 
   {
    $sthiti2--;
   }
  } 
  else  
  { 
   $sthiti2 = $text_size  ;  
   $chale_chalo = 0; 
  }
  $modified_substring = substr($modified_substring,$sthiti1, $sthiti2);
  $modified_substring = Replace_Symbols($modified_substring,$array_one_length,$array_one,$array_two,$text);
 }
 return $modified_substring;
}
function Replace_Symbols($modified_substring,$array_one_length,$array_one,$array_two,$text)
{
 if( $modified_substring != "" )  // if stringto be converted is non-blank then no need of any processing.
 {
  for ($input_symbol_idx = 0;  $input_symbol_idx < $array_one_length; $input_symbol_idx++ )
  {
   $idx = true ;  
   while ($idx != false) 
   {
    $modified_substring = str_replace($array_one[$input_symbol_idx],$array_two[$input_symbol_idx],$modified_substring);
    $idx = strpos($modified_substring,$array_one[$input_symbol_idx]);
   }
  }
  //$position_of_i = strpos(utf8_decode($modified_substring),"f");
  $set_of_matras = "अ आ इ ई उ ऊ ए ऐ ओ औ ा ि ी ु ू ृ े ै ो ौ ं : ँ ॅ";
  $position_of_R = strpos(utf8_decode($modified_substring), "Z");
  while ($position_of_R > 0 )  // while-04
        {
   $probable_position_of_half_r = $position_of_R - 1;
   $charecter_at_probable_position_of_half_r = $array_two[array_search($text{$probable_position_of_half_r}, $array_one)];
   var_dump(preg_match($charecter_at_probable_position_of_half_r,$set_of_matras) != false);
   while(preg_match($charecter_at_probable_position_of_half_r,$set_of_matras)){
    $probable_position_of_half_r = $probable_position_of_half_r - 1;
    echo $probable_position_of_half_r;
    $charecter_at_probable_position_of_half_r = $modified_substring{$probable_position_of_half_r};
   }
   $charecter_to_be_replaced = $array_two[array_search(substr($text, $probable_position_of_half_r, $position_of_R - $probable_position_of_half_r), $array_one)];
   $new_replacement_string = "र्".$charecter_to_be_replaced;
   $charecter_to_be_replaced = $charecter_to_be_replaced."Z";
   $modified_substring = str_replace($charecter_to_be_replaced,$new_replacement_string,$modified_substring);
   $position_of_R = strpos(utf8_decode($modified_substring), "Z");
   $position_of_R--;
  }
 }
 return $modified_substring;
}
?>
```

PHP

```
preg_match($charecter_at_probable_position_of_half_r,$set_of_matras) != false;
```

return false,

where as in

Javascript

```
 console.log(set_of_matras.match(charecter_at_probable_position_of_half_r) != null);
```

it returns true;